# My second rebus is only half

Tags: rebus

This is the second rebus I have created: [image: rebus]

I hope you like it! It is one word.

Comment: What did you use to create the image? Just curious, is all :)

Comment: @user477343 Adobe photoshop. I use a Mac.

Comment: Can you download the software on a Mac computer, do you know? Macs don't run on Microsoft, so I hope that isn't an issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

haha that was pretty creative. I'm guessing

> doe

because

> domino - minnow + e = do + e

Comment: I thought the fish was a [carp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_carp)... but  it has scales!

Comment: @user477343 tbh I had no idea what kind of fish it was, but 'minnow' just popped out at me from 'domino'!

Comment: @KevinL At first I thought dome, then I thought doe then I saw your answer. so… accept!! No, I thought of this before I saw this answer and it's better so yeah this is now the intended answer

Comment: You mean that the intended answer is different? @YoutRied

Comment: @KevinL perhaps it was just a miscalculation :)

Comment: Lol is it really possible to miscalculate an answer? @user477343

Comment: You could be right; I *doe*n't see much of a possibility. (Sorry but I had to) :D